# Static content not loading status code 302 Java Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security

After I added security to my application, static content stopped loading, it makes a request for JS and CSS but status code 303 is returned.

Only raw HTML is shown.

Here is my config also i made changes to the location of static content, properties file below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
                    request.requestMatchers("/backoffice/**").authenticated()
                            .requestMatchers("/index/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll();
                })
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

properties file

```
spring.messages.basename=lang/messages
# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=utf-8
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/
# Static resources
spring.web.resources.cache.period=0
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:src/main/resources/static/,file:uploads/ProductImages/
# Connection string
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${CONNECTION_STRING}
# Custom File Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=5MB
# Custom folder for serving product images
```

When I delete security config content loads normally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll();`
I needed to use

```
.requestMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "img/**").permitAll();
```

`since my resources.static-locations` are set to static folder where I keep all my static content.

Comment: I also wonder if there is a better way to do this?